# Programming C if statements

Tags: c, if-statement, quadratic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void){

double a,b,c, x, y, z1, z2;

printf("Enter the coefficients of a polynomial(ax^2+bx+c): ");
scanf("%lfx^2+%lfx+%lf",&a,&b,&c);

z1=(-b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/2*a;
z2=(-b-sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/2*a;
printf("%lf and %lf",z1,z2);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

I want an IF statement such that if any polynomial does not have a value, it would be 1.
Say that I want my polynomial is x^2+7x+6; I would have to input as 1x^2+7x+6 to have the output values.

How would I write an if statement that if a, b, or c doesn't have a value, then it will equal to 1?

Comment: What does it mean to not have a value? What input would cause that case to occur? Can you give some example inputs and what you would expect the resultant values of a, b and c would be?

Comment: @sharth I will only receive the values if I input 1x^2+7x+6 rather than x^2+7x+6. I want to write an if statement such that if there are no coefficient values, then set the variable to 1.

Comment: "How would I write an if statement" - you can't. You have to handle this probem when parsing the input (and not after).

Comment: How do you want user input to be for `x^2+7x+6` and how do you want it to be for `7x^2+x+6`? Both can't be `7 6`, or you don't know which is which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set values of a,b,c =1 by default..
Now create a condition that example if a user enter char rather than int or float . it does nothing {use error handling for that,}

Or take all a,b,c input as string then typecast to to double, and use error handler if error occur assign it value 1